# Git partial clone: how to disable dynamic object fetching?

Tags: git, git-clone

I have invoked a Git *partial clone* to clone a repository without any blobs:

```
git clone --filter=blob:none https://server/repo.git
```

Now I would like to experiment with this repository to see which operations are locally possible without Git dynamically fetching missing objects from the promisor remote. Is there some Git config option to disable dynamic fetching and instead let me run into "missing object" errors?

Comment: you could just remove the remote from the `.git/config` file in the repository or use `git remote remove origin` which will have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks, @toydarian , that seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with removing the remote. Either by removing the remote from the `.git/config` file or running `git remote remove origin`.

Answer (score 3):

Support for [partial clones](https://git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone) is still a work in progress, so there may be better solutions for this in the future.

As of right now, Git will only fetch missing objects from *promisor* remotes. From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone#_current_limitations):

> Dynamic object fetching will only ask promisor remotes for missing objects. We assume that promisor remotes have a complete view of the repository and can satisfy all such requests.

This is listed as a *limitation*, so it may very well change in the future. However, as of right now, you can use this to your advantage by simply telling Git that the `origin` remote isn't a promisor by saying:

```
git config remote.origin.promisor false
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint, I agree with your understanding. However with Git 2.28 this limitation doesn't seem to be present anymore. The object is still fetched, despite of setting `remote.origin.promisor` to `false` (or even getting rid of this config key completely).