Why does `git diff` want to connect to remote when branches are up to date locally
This is a question when googled brings up results pertaining to "comparing local with remote", and not much specific to my problem.
I have two branches checked out locally, and up to date.
When I then do a git diff I get the following output:
me@work:~/dev/project/myuberproject (branchA)
$ git diff branchB
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.ourgitlabserver.com: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: could not fetch e0e7c...2115 from promisor remote

Here I am not connected to the VPN on which the gitlab server is reachable.
The point of the question is: why does it want to go to remote to do a diff on two fully locally checked out and up to date branches?

Partial clone? Seems Git wanna fetch not yet fetched objects. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63279262/git-partial-clone-how-to-disable-dynamic-object-fetching , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Partial+clone

Does your repository have any diff driver that involves git-fetch?

@phd Partial as in sparse? eg $ git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout --sparse ssh://git@gitlab.ourgitlabserver.com:10022/abc/myuberproject.git myuberproject ? This is what I do yes, this codebase is in a huge monorepo. I tried to do a directory diff on parts that I know is sparse checked-out, eg git diff branchB -- directoryX and that is instantaneous, without a query to remote. It's just odd then that it shows up now as I've always done it this way. I've never had the above response before.

@eugenevd It's not sparse. Shallow clone (--depth), sparse checkout (--sparse) and partial clone (--filter) are 3 different ways to limit local repo and local workingdir sizes and network traffic. In your case git diff is trying to access not fetched (due to --filter=blob:none) blobs. Git completes partial clone behind the scene if it can. In your case it cannot hence the error,

@eugenevd To fix your problem you need to turn your VPN on to allow Git to fetch necessary objects. And turn it on every time Git needs to fetch more. Or avoid using Git commands that access that blobs but how much you could without them? git diff and git log would be forbidden, esp. git log -p and git show.
